# Bootstrap 4: how to change the order of a columns when the screen size changes

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I want my website to have on md size screens and larger a phone on the right and text on the left. But once the screen size is smaller than md, I want the text to be bellow the phone.

```
<section id="" class="pt-3 mt-3">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 my-auto text-right">
          <h3 class="display-3 lato_text">Description</h3>
          <p class="lead">On the map, click on an OddJob to get a quick preview.</p>
          <p class="lead">In the preview, you will see the title and price of the job.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="text-center">
            <img id="phone-screenshot" src="img/JobFullDesc.jpg" class="img-fluid mb-3">
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

How would I change my html to make it so that on md size screens and below, the text would be below the phone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make use of Bootstrap 4's **[`order` classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes)**.

Unfortunately Bootstrap 4's layout classes are **[mobile-first](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints)**, so you'll need to specify that the text should come *after* the image by default, and  *override* this for large screens.

To drop the text below the image on medium and smaller devices, you'll want to give the text the classes `order-2` and `order-md-1`, and the image the classes `order-1` and `order-md-2`.

This can be seen in the following:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section id="" class="pt-3 mt-3">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 my-auto text-right order-2 order-md-1">
        <h3 class="display-3 lato_text">Description</h3>
        <p class="lead">On the map, click on an OddJob to get a quick preview.</p>
        <p class="lead">In the preview, you will see the title and price of the job.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 order-1 order-md-2">
        <div class="text-center">
          <img id="phone-screenshot" src="http://placehold.it/100" class="img-fluid mb-3">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Note that on small screens (such as with this snippet in the default view), the image comes before the text, yet with larger screens (such as with this snippet in `Full page` view) the image comes after the text.

Comment: I tried adding order-md-2(and 1) but it seems to work opposite. So on size above md, the img is on the left and text on right. And for sm, it would be text on top and img on the bottom.

Comment: @TamirOffen -- You've got the classes the wrong way around. `order-2 order-md-1` goes on the description, and `order-1 order-md-2` goes on the image :)

Comment: Bootstrap 4 layout classes being mobile-first is the real gotcha here. Thank you.